# how to get android default font list programmatically?

Tags: android, android-fonts

I am trying to create app which provide text formatting (like font style , font size , font color). So I want default fonts provided by android as a list to be shown in drop-down. Selecting font from drop-down will change the Text dynamically.
Can anyone help , how can I achieve this either via XML or programmatically ?

See the image how it must look like

[image]

Comment: For ordinary widgets, there are only three options: serif, sans-serif, and monospace. Fonts are not part of the Android SDK.

Comment: Ok. So how I can get more fonts?

Comment: That's your job. Package some in your app. Or, download some from the Internet. Pay attention to the font licensing terms, of course.

Comment: @Pallavi its making a one comman class for the set different type of font and in activity to set after bind text view.

Comment: @HardikParmar I need to put .ttf files in asset folder, Correct?

Comment: @Pallavi yes this for the different different font type.

Comment: @HardikParmar , but how many .ttf files I will download?
And also it will increase the size of the package. So is there any better way.

Comment: @Pallavi how many font size you want ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111517/discussion-between-pallavi-and-hardik-parmar).

Answer (score 3):

font list is saved in `Typeface` class as a static field `Map<Stirng, Typeface> sSystemFontMap`. you just need to get this field. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37759420/5855027).

Answer (score 2):

There are only three system wide fonts in Android SDK.

> - normal
> - serif
> - monospace

More info : [click here](http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/List_of_fonts_included_with_each_device)

Comment: Ok. So how I can get more fonts?

Comment: need to add your app itself