# How to get name of the font applied on the textview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fonts

```
Textview label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_title);
label.setText("Solve My Issue !");
Log.d("TAG","Font-Family : "+ String.valueOf(label.getTypeface()));
```

When i see the log it return `Font-Family : android.graphics.Typeface@7f37f870`

How to know the name of the font family ? Is it possible ?

Comment: getTypeface() method return [Typeface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html#getStyle()) class object check this and use methods from it to access attr from typeface

Comment: i think you miss the link please share it

Comment: is it possible that i get the exact name of the font

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`getTypeface()` method returns the Typeface of `label`, while this Tyepface instance is a value of `Map<String, Typeface> sSystemFontMap`, which is a static field of `Typeface`. So now you get the value, and with reflection you can get the map `sSystemFontMap`, then want to find the key, which is exactly the name of font.

```
protected Map<String, Typeface> getSSystemFontMap() {
    Map<String, Typeface> sSystemFontMap = null;
    try {
        //Typeface typeface = Typeface.class.newInstance();
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.NORMAL);
        Field f = Typeface.class.getDeclaredField("sSystemFontMap");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        sSystemFontMap = (Map<String, Typeface>) f.get(typeface);
        for (Map.Entry<String, Typeface> entry : sSystemFontMap.entrySet()) {
            Log.d("FontMap", entry.getKey() + " ---> " + entry.getValue() + "\n");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sSystemFontMap;
}

private static List<String> getKeyWithValue(Map map, Typeface value) {
    Set set = map.entrySet();
    List<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Object obj : set) {
        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) obj;
        if (entry.getValue().equals(value)) {
            String str = (String) entry.getKey();
            arr.add(str);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

I tested it, and the List `arr` contain below String

```
sans-serif
tahoma
arial
helvetica
verdana
```

That's not strange, because Android system use one same font as above five names. (Maybe some differences in various system version, for more information goto `/system/etc/fonts.xml`)

```
<family name="sans-serif">
    <font weight="100" style="normal">Roboto-Thin.ttf</font>
    <font weight="100" style="italic">Roboto-ThinItalic.ttf</font>
    <font weight="300" style="normal">Roboto-Light.ttf</font>
    <font weight="300" style="italic">Roboto-LightItalic.ttf</font>
    <font weight="400" style="normal">Roboto-Regular.ttf</font>
    <font weight="400" style="italic">Roboto-Italic.ttf</font>
    <font weight="500" style="normal">Roboto-Medium.ttf</font>
    <font weight="500" style="italic">Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf</font>
    <font weight="900" style="normal">Roboto-Black.ttf</font>
    <font weight="900" style="italic">Roboto-BlackItalic.ttf</font>
    <font weight="700" style="normal">Roboto-Bold.ttf</font>
    <font weight="700" style="italic">Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf</font>
</family>
<!-- Note that aliases must come after the fonts they reference. -->
<alias name="sans-serif-thin" to="sans-serif" weight="100" />
<alias name="sans-serif-light" to="sans-serif" weight="300" />
<alias name="sans-serif-medium" to="sans-serif" weight="500" />
<alias name="sans-serif-black" to="sans-serif" weight="900" />
<alias name="arial" to="sans-serif" />
<alias name="helvetica" to="sans-serif" />
<alias name="tahoma" to="sans-serif" />
<alias name="verdana" to="sans-serif" />
```

from this you can see. `sans-serif,tahoma,arial,helvetica,verdana` are same thing. different names of font family `sans-serif`

Comment: it return me **sans-serif, tahoma, arial, helvetica, verdana** so what it means exactly ?

Comment: In `/system/etc/fonts.xml`, Android system define these five names refer to 'Roboto' font . So sum up, **the font is `Roboto`**

Comment: Is there any simpler way of doing this ? As I can see in the official documentation for Typeface, unfortunately, there is no property or method called Typeface.NAME or Typeface.getName()

Comment: Thanks! This works well, but there's some warning. Is there any way to fix these warning? 
1. Cannot resolve field 'sSystemFontMap' 
 at Typeface.class.getDeclaredField("sSystemFontMap");
2. Unchecked cast: 'java.lang.Object' to 'java.util.Map<java.lang.String,android.graphics.Typeface>'  at (Map<String, Typeface>) f.get(typeface);

Comment: It's utterly insane that this is the only way to do this simple task.