# How i can get Android System fonts list that is already installed and apply to custom keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-fonts

I have to make an application that can retrieve font list that is pre-installed with Android OS. I need to display system font and can select to set that font for my application.

I have number of feature in my application and i have to get random system font and   apply this font style to my custom soft keyboard. how i can apply this font to my custom soft keyboard.

**How i can access this font and apply to my application?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve a list of available/installed fonts in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532397/how-to-retrieve-a-list-of-available-installed-fonts-in-android)

Comment: Okkey This is duplicated i will delete if i get answer from it.

Comment: Don't delete, but accept that this is duplicate by clicking the button above this question.

Comment: @NoumanCh Do it for me .

Comment: @VasudevVyas I can't mark it as duplicate you have to do this by yourself. check this link https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79916/is-it-possible-to-mark-my-own-question-as-duplicate-of-another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to retrieve a list of available/installed fonts in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532397/how-to-retrieve-a-list-of-available-installed-fonts-in-android)

From above original question i got my answer but i am extending my answer with what i really wanted to do.  how can we access those font in our application.

We can access system from path using this function `(Typeface.createFromFile("your file")`

```
      String path = "/system/fonts";
      File file = new File(path);
      File ff[] = file.listFiles();

       for(int i = 0 ; i < ff.length ; i++){
       fontName.setText(file.getName());
       fontName.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromFile(ff[i]));   
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

File Manager Class to Load System Fonts

```
public class FontManager {
    // This function enumerates all fonts on Android system and returns the HashMap with the font
    // absolute file name as key, and the font literal name (embedded into the font) as value.
    static public HashMap< String, String > enumerateFonts()
    {
        String[] fontdirs = { "/system/fonts", "/system/font", "/data/fonts" };
        HashMap< String, String > fonts = new HashMap< String, String >();
        TTFAnalyzer analyzer = new TTFAnalyzer();

        for ( String fontdir : fontdirs )
        {
            File dir = new File( fontdir );

            if ( !dir.exists() )
                continue;

            File[] files = dir.listFiles();

            if ( files == null )
                continue;

            for ( File file : files )
            {
                String fontname = analyzer.getTtfFontName( file.getAbsolutePath() );


                if ( fontname != null ) {
//                    Log.d("fonts", fontname+" : "+file.getAbsolutePath());
                    fonts.put(file.getAbsolutePath(), fontname);
                }

            }




        }

        return fonts.isEmpty() ? null : fonts;
    }
```

Font Detail Model Class:

```
public class FontDetail
{
    String sFontNames;
    String sFontPaths;
    String sFontType;

    public FontDetail(String sFontNames, String sFontPaths, String sFontType)
    {
        this.sFontNames = sFontNames;
        this.sFontPaths = sFontPaths;
        this.sFontType = sFontType;
    }

    public String getsFontNames()
    {
        return sFontNames;
    }

    public void setsFontNames(String sFontNames)
    {
        this.sFontNames = sFontNames;
    }

    public String getsFontPaths()
    {
        return sFontPaths;
    }

    public void setsFontPaths(String sFontPaths)
    {
        this.sFontPaths = sFontPaths;
    }

    public String getsFontType()
    {
        return sFontType;
    }

    public void setsFontType(String sFontType) {
        this.sFontType = sFontType;
    }
}
```

Array List to Hold Fonts List:

```
   ArrayList<FontDetail> arrLstFontDetail = new ArrayList<FontDetail>();
```

Load System Fonts in arrLstFontDetails:

```
public void loadSystemFontsToListView() {
      try {
         Iterator<?> iter = FontManager.enumerateFonts().entrySet().iterator();

         while (iter.hasNext()) {
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            Map.Entry mEntry = (Map.Entry) iter.next();
            LogMaintain.ShowLog(LogMaintain.LogType.Error, "System : " + (String) mEntry.getValue() + "Key: " + (String) mEntry.getKey());
            arrLstFontDetail.add(new FontDetail((String) mEntry.getValue(), (String) mEntry.getKey(), "System"));
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typeface is the class which would help you to get the list of all the fonts installed. Then you can map the fonts. This link could help out from it :
[How to get name of the font applied on the textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37696436/how-to-get-name-of-the-font-applied-on-the-textview/37759420#37759420)